# What are the invariants of a number field?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, invariant-theory

How is defined an invariant of a field? Given a certain field extension $L/K$, is it related with the Galois group ${\rm Gal}(L/K)$? 
In the case of number fields, which are the invariants associated to these extensions? For example, I remember that the relative discriminant is an invariant, but any other examples? Is it possible that the maximum power of an element $a$, i.e. the maximum $h$ such that $a=b^h$ for some element $b$, is again an invariant?

I know the question is very broad, so any bibliografy/reference suggestion would be great too!

Thanks in advance

Comment: An invariant is just a number, group, etc. attached to a field $k$. We could talk about dimension, for example, as an invariant of vector spaces. Usually we want field invariants to depend only on $k$ up to abstract isomorphism (or an isomorphism of field extensions, etc.), and thus it should be independent of, for example, a particular choice of embedding $k \to \mathbb{C}$ for $k/\mathbb{Q}$ a number field. Examples of invariants include the characteristic (not very interesting for number fields), cardinality (ditto), cohomological dimension, class number, and so on.

Comment: Also, this is a very broad question. If you want a useful answer, it would probably be better to ask something more specific or indicate what kind of background you have.

Comment: Sorry I know it's a broad question, in fact I was mainly asking for a bibliography suggestion (my level is....beginner in algebraic NT!). The specific question concerned the perfect $h$-power and, based on what you said, probably I should prove that if I pick an element $a\in k$ for which $a=b^h$, applying any embedding $\sigma:k\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ I get $\sigma(a)=\sigma(b)^h$, which is true since $\sigma$ is an homomorphism, am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Given an element, you can always take powers of it. There will be no maximum power in the way you've described. You could ask about roots of unity, or about roots of elements of $\mathbb Q$. Having an $n$th root of $a\in\mathbb Q$ would be an invariant.

Comment: What I mean is: suppose $K$ field with $s\in K$ perfect $h$-power. Acting with any embedding on $a$ you get in principle another element $a' \neq a$, but also $a'$ is a perfect $h$-power, isn't it?

Comment: Every field has a perfect $h$-power for every $h$. Take $a\in K$ to be any non-unit. Then $a^h$ is a perfect $h$-power. You want to know if a *specific* element is an $h$-power. That property depends on the choice of isomorphism. Without already knowing the isomorphism, you have no way of telling me what $a'$ is.

Comment: By contrast, an invariant could be "$K$ has a square root of $2$". Any isomorphism will preserve $2$. Therefore, in any number field, I can ask "does $2$ have a square root". In your case, my question would have to be "does $\sigma(b)$ have an $h$th root", which doesn't make sense without already knowing $\sigma$.

Answer (score 1):

I will try it with a short answer (to the title question), only giving two further invariants. Besides the discriminant also the [ideal class group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group) and its order, the class number
are invariants, and the ring of integers of a number field in general. Furthermore 
[Minkowski's bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_bound), and the invariants involved there, i.e., the number of real and complex embeddings.